# After change wpf button IsMouseOver trigger color not work

Tags: c#, wpf

this is my button code

```
 public class MetroButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MoseOverBrushProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PressedBrushProperty;

    public MetroButton():base()
    {

        var resource = new ResourceDictionary
        {
            Source = new Uri("/Parking.Component.Ui;component/Styles/ButtonMetro.xaml",
                     UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        };
        Style = resource["ButtonMetro"] as Style;
        //SetResourceReference(StyleProperty, Style);
    }
    static MetroButton()
    {

        MoseOverBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MoseOverBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(MetroButton));
        PressedBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PressedBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(MetroButton));
    }


    public Brush MoseOverBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)base.GetValue(MoseOverBrushProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(MoseOverBrushProperty, value); }            
    }
    public Brush PressedBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)base.GetValue(PressedBrushProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(PressedBrushProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

and I use this style for my button

```
<Style   x:Key="ButtonMetro" TargetType="{ x:Type LochalUI:MetroButton}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="MoseOverBrush" Value="#FF3F62FD"/>
    <Setter Property="PressedBrush" Value="#FF000099"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF6B9AFF"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type LochalUI:MetroButton}">
                <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="4" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=MoseOverBrush , RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />

                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=PressedBrush , RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**but the problem is there when i put color for my button background like below code:**

```
 <UI:MetroButton HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132" Height="107" Background="#FF09CD00"  >
        <Grid>
            <Label Content="تنظیمات" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="5,5,5,12" Foreground="White" Margin="5"/>
        </Grid>
    </UI:MetroButton>
```

**the IsMouseOver changer color and IsPressed Triggers not work.**

(I don't want use static resource in my setters)
Changing other properties has no effect just changing background made this problem.

Comment: Style triggers can only change properties set in the style, not with tag attributes. You need to remove `Background="#FF09CD00"` from the `UI:MetroButton` tag.

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev if you put in triggers static value it will be work great test code before give negative  point

Comment: I have found the solution, you were missing the `TargetName="border"` as the style was trying to apply to the `TextBlock` not the `Border`.

Comment: @XAMlMAX after try your code in mouse over color change to white not what we set on  mouseover brush

Comment: Your Style setter has 2 setters, one sets foreground to white and the other the background to whatever you set it.

Comment: the background color if you watch i set  MoseOverBrush="#FF2F00CD" but after run the code in this trigger it change to white not mouseoverbrush

Comment: yup, I found it through `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:MetroButton}`. :-)

Comment: @XAMlMAX thank you freand one of the the problems was one of them you said in border name and another was in binding

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev solve the problem is the way not removing problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer problem was in 2 place:

first one when we use trigger in

```
 <ControlTemplate.Triggers/>
```

you have sure you set your setter set property on the currect object

and the secend one is in the binding we have change

```
Value="{Binding Path=MoseOverBrush , RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

to

```
Value="{Binding Path=MoseOverBrush , RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

because `MoseOverBrush` is parrent property not the ControlTemplate property